# What is the purpose of Retrofit and RxJava when getting data from a server?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java

I saw many examples/tutorials on the internet even here on stackoverflow on getting data from a back-end server using Retrofit and RxJava but I cannot understand what is the purpose of each one of this technologies.

If anyone can explain me I'll be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: In short, retrofit is a powerful library for network connections and rxjava is a library which enables support for modern programming language features which are not part of java 7, which is the default version in android. For more detailed information, I'd recommend to have a look at the documentation of those libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Retrofit` helps you to provide a high-level abstraction for your network interface.

> [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) turns your HTTP API into a Java interface.

So you do not have to do this manually all the time: just annotate...

RxJava introduces a concept of [reactive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming), and RxJava2 is a beloved dependency in android community. Talking about it's connection with retrofit: by default, retrofit returns a [`Call`](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html) from every request, which, to run asynchronously, requires a callback to be provided which will be afterwards invoked after finishing an operation. RxJava2 adapter to the Retrofit makes it easier: it removes a callback and gives you finer control over thread environment and task cancellation, so you can just do the next thing:

```
myApi.doSomething()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.Io()) //run network request on Io thread pool
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) //emit the result in android's main thread
    .subscribe(result -> processResult(result));
```

Whereas your interface declaration powered with Retrofit will be just something like this:

```
public interface MyApi {

    @GET("/endpoint")
    public Single<Result> doSomething();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Retrfit` is famous android networking library. It handles the network connectivity & other network related things (Please ref : https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client). RxJava is a concept of Subscriber and Observer pattern for getting uptodate results for particular update/event.